# Configure JIRA default list of watchers

Tags: notifications, release, bug-tracking, jira

I'm looking for an option to make JIRA apply a default group of people to watcher list of some task. Is that possible to do out of the box?

Especially, whenever we do a release I'd like to create a task for it with subtasks and make sure that a predefined group of people gets notifications about them being updated/closed.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at this thread where a workaround is mentioned: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-5493